# how to use an array as a variable?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

i want to use an array as a variable

this is the array

```
    Array
    (
        [code] => Ty7nB
        [image_src] => /captcha/simple-php-captcha-master/simple-php-captcha.php?_CAPTCHA&t=0.42191900+1410018068
    )
```

and the variable $code must be the [code] of the array 
for example :

```
    <?php
     echo 'Your code is '.$code;
    ?>
```

the result must be

```
    Your code is Ty7nB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
 echo 'Your code is '.$array['code'];
?>
```

See [the manual for working with arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) as this is basic PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
<?php
 echo 'Your code is '.$array['code'];
?>
```